# C# Async TCP client enter in infinity loop after server disconnection

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, tcp, client

I've some issue with my code.. Easy I write a question here .

I've written a new class to have an async TCP client. My issue is very easy, on server disconnection the receive callback is called in infinity loop without any bytes read.. The RAM of the project is exponential. It's incredible for me, I don't have the beginning of a little lead to solve this one ..
I've tried a lot of solutions to solve this issue, without success ...

I'm a newbie in code ..

[Ram after server disconnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dztAo.png)

```
public class TcpClientAsync : IDisposable
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Constant
    #region Constant
    private const string SOURCE = "TcpClient";
    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Constructor
    #region Constructor
    public TcpClientAsync()
    {
        mpr_timeoutConnection.Elapsed += Mpr_timeoutConnection_Elapsed;
        mpr_timeoutConnection.AutoReset = false;

    }

    ~TcpClientAsync()
    {
        StopAndClean();
    }

    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Private Member
    #region Private Member
    private IPAddress mpr_remoteIp = IPAddress.Any;
    private IPEndPoint mpr_remoteEndPoint;
    private Socket mpr_clientSocket;
    private Timer mpr_timeoutConnection = new Timer(5000);
    private bool mpr_checkFrameSize = false;

    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Protected Member
    #region Protected Member

    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Public Member
    #region Public Member


    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// EventHandler
    #region EventHandler
    public event EventHandler<Frame> OnNewDataReceived = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<TcpClientState> OnNewState = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<Event> OnNewEvent = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<EndPoint> OnBeginConnect = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<EndPoint> OnConnect = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler OnDisconnect = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<Frame> OnNewDataSent = delegate { };

    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Properties
    #region Properties

    public double ConnectionTimeout
    {
        get
        {
            return mpr_timeoutConnection.Interval;
        }
        set
        {
            mpr_timeoutConnection.Interval = value;
        }
    }

    public bool CheckFrameSize
    {
        get { return mpr_checkFrameSize; }
        set
        {
            mpr_checkFrameSize = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Event Callback
    #region EventCallback
    private void Mpr_timeoutConnection_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Timeout for connection", "Timeout for connect remote tcp server."));
        StopAndClean();
        mpr_timeoutConnection.Enabled = false;
    }

    #endregion

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Private Method
    #region Private Method
    private void StartService(int port = 2401, string remoteAddress = "0.0.0.0")
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IPAddress.TryParse(remoteAddress, out mpr_remoteIp))
                {
                    OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Warning, "Fail to parse ip address", "Try to retrieve by hostname"));
                    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(remoteAddress);
                    if (ipHostInfo == null)
                    {
                        OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error for retrieve remote end point", ""));
                        StopAndClean();
                        return;
                    }

                    mpr_remoteIp = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                }

                mpr_remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(mpr_remoteIp, port);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error for retrieve remote endpoint", ex.Message, ex));
                StopAndClean();
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
                mpr_clientSocket = new Socket(mpr_remoteIp.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                try
                {
                    // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
                    mpr_clientSocket.BeginConnect(mpr_remoteEndPoint,
                        new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), mpr_clientSocket);

                    OnBeginConnect?.Invoke(this, mpr_remoteEndPoint);
                    OnNewState?.Invoke(this, TcpClientState.ConnectionInProgress);
                    if (mpr_timeoutConnection.Enabled)
                        mpr_timeoutConnection.Enabled = false;
                    mpr_timeoutConnection.Enabled = true;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error to launch connection", ex.Message, ex));
                    StopAndClean();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error to create or launch socket connection", ex.Message, ex));
                StopAndClean();
                return;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to start tcp client", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete the connection.  
                client.EndConnect(ar);

                try
                {
                    // Set new state
                    mpr_timeoutConnection.Enabled = false;
                    OnNewState?.Invoke(this, TcpClientState.Connected);
                    OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Event, "Remote partner connected : " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), ""));
                    OnConnect?.Invoke(this, client.RemoteEndPoint);

                    // Make receive callback
                    try
                    {
                        // Create the state object.  
                        StateObject state = new StateObject();
                        state.workSocket = client;

                        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
                        mpr_clientSocket.BeginReceive(state.frame.FrameBytes, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to create receive callback", ex.Message, ex));
                        StopAndClean();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to update the state", ex.Message, ex));
                    StopAndClean();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to stop connection state", ex.Message, ex));
                StopAndClean();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to open the connection with server", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the client socket
                // from the asynchronous state object.  
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the remote device.  
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                try
                {
                    
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                            state.frame.FrameBytes, 0, bytesRead));

                        if (bytesRead != StateObject.BufferSize && mpr_checkFrameSize)
                        {
                            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Incomplete frame received from component, frame size expected : " + StateObject.BufferSize.ToString(), ""));
                            OnNewDataReceived?.Invoke(this, state.frame);
                            StopAndClean();
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Warning, "Empty frame received from component", ""));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to encode received frame", ex.Message, ex));
                    StopAndClean();
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    OnNewDataReceived?.Invoke(this, state.frame);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to share received data", ex.Message, ex));
                    StopAndClean();
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    // Create new callback for a new incoming frame
                    StateObject newState = new StateObject();
                    newState.workSocket = client;

                    client.BeginReceive(newState.frame.FrameBytes, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), newState);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to create receive callback", ex.Message, ex));
                    StopAndClean();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to close socket for read buffer", ex.Message, ex));
                StopAndClean();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to receive data from server", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void Send(Socket client, Frame data)
    {
        if (!mpr_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Warning, "Fail to send frame, not connected", ""));
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Create state object
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
            state.frame = data;

            try
            {
                // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
                client.BeginSend(state.frame.FrameBytes, 0, state.frame.Lenght, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error for create the send callback", ex.Message, ex));
                StopAndClean();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Fail to create the send callback", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }

    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);

            // Update hex dump
            OnNewDataSent?.Invoke(this, state.frame);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error in send callback", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }
    }


    private void StopAndClean()
    {
        if (mpr_clientSocket != null)
        {
            if (mpr_clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                OnDisconnect?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                mpr_clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }

            mpr_clientSocket.Close();
            mpr_clientSocket.Dispose();
        }

        OnNewState?.Invoke(this, TcpClientState.Disconnect);

        mpr_timeoutConnection.Enabled = false;

    }
    #endregion

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Protected Method
    #region Protected Method

    #endregion

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Public Method
    #region Public Method

    public void Start(int port = 2401, string ipAddress = "0.0.0.0")
    {
        try
        {
            StartService(port, ipAddress);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error to start the client", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            StopAndClean();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error to stop the client", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void SendFrame(Frame frame)
    {
        try
        {
            Send(mpr_clientSocket, frame);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnNewEvent?.Invoke(this, new Event(SOURCE, EventType.Error, "Error to send frame", ex.Message, ex));
            StopAndClean();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StopAndClean();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Your receive callback always calls `BeginReceive()`, even when the connection is being shutdown. Don't do that. See duplicate.

Comment: It's impossible to run your code and very difficult to debug it mentally - please consider simplifying it so that someone can help.

Comment: Thank you for your time.. This is solved. 
But you know why the socket in "server mode" has another reaction on client disconnection? It's easy to catch the socket exception and define the reason by the exception.